# Create new variable from condition on 2 distant DB tables

Tags: r, dplyr, r-dbi, dbplyr

I have in my PostgreSQL DB two separate tables:

```
table_a <- tbl(con, "table_a")

table_b <- tbl(con, "table_b")
```

I'd like to create a new variable like this:

```
table_c <- table_a %>%
mutate(variable_a = ifelse(a %in% table_b$a & table_b$b == 100, TRUE, FALSE)
```

But I get an error message related to `table_b$a`

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: [...] CASE WHEN ("a" IN () AND  = 2...
                                 ^
```

Comment: Please share content of `table_a` and `table_b`. It seems `table_b` is not created for some reason. The `mutate` line got 1 less `)` but error should be different for that.

Comment: It is created, that’s why I’m surprised. It appears I have the same problem after I `collect()` the tables.

Comment: May be its worth restarting `RStudio`. Can you please try one thing: Print both `table_a` and `table_b` and see whats happen?

Comment: I have the 10 first rows from a lazy query for each table.

Comment: can you try `%IN%` instead of `%in%` ? and please mention your DBMS

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an issue `converting` `%in` logic from `dplyr` sentence to `sqlquery`. An alternate way to write the same `query` using `left_join` can be as:

```
table_c <- table_a %>% left_join(table_b, by="a") %>%
mutate(variable_a = ifelse( !is.na(b) & b == 100, TRUE, FALSE))
```

**Note:** It has been assumed that `b` column is only part of `table_b` otherwise it has to be refereed as `table_b.y`